# Are Stripe cookies "strictly necessary" therefore not requiring consent?

Tags: http, cookies, stripe-payments, session-cookies, gdprconsentform

**TLDR: Are Stripe cookies "essential" cookies that do not require consent?**

As many of you may know, Stripe is a payment processor and they require that websites using their platform serve the users with their "stripe.js" which applies several cookies.

The cookies are used for tracking, so they sort of come under GDPR, but the tracking is for strictly necessary purposes (fraud prevention) so it sort of also doesn't come under GDPR.

Do I need to irritate users with an accept cookies banner for these Stripe cookies or not? I think it would impair functionality if they were not set, so I'm leaning towards "No, I don't need to ask"

Comment: I would confirm with Stripe's support on this: https://support.stripe.com

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I did just ask this morning following your comment, but as I suspected, they were very careful to word their response in such a way as to not definitively confirm either way (it was kind of "here is a statement, make up your own mind on it")